# Drivers difference between Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-8, drivers, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried to use Epson Perfection 3490 Photo scanner in Windows Server 2012 R2, but couldn't install drivers. What I know for certain - this scanner is working in Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Are differences between Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 R2 really so big in order not to be able to use same drivers?

Comment: It depends. Without knowing all the hooks and handles the drivers are attempting to use, there's no way to tell which specific difference is affecting you, and there are too many difference to list meaningfully here. Does the printer state that it is compatible with Server 2012 R2? If not, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Yes; But have you tried to simply modify the .inf file?  Typically it's just a string of supported operating systems that prevent a driver especially if it works on Windows 8 and Windows 10 then it's unlikely it work on a Server version of Windows.

Comment: look in the "C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log" file to see what fails when you try to install the driver. maybe it has a dependency that is not installed in Server versions

Comment: any update? have you looked into the log file?